# How to use Simple Query String Query in Django Elasticsearch-dsl python?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am unable to find any documentation regarding how do I implement Simple Query String Query in my Django Elasticsearch-dsl

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html

Can someone guide me through it?

This is my search function.

```
def search(q_string):
client = Elasticsearch(
    [
        'elasticsearch'
    ]
)
s = Search(using=client).query(SimpleQueryString(q_string))
```

Above code is showing me paring error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the same structure as the `json` document - whatever keys in the object will become kwargs, so:

```
SimpleQueryString(query="QUERY", fields=[...], default_operator='and')
```

also please don't create a new instance of `Elasticsearch` for every search, use a global instance and reuse it.

Hope this helps!